# Dead TCP connections

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I use Indy10 and Delphi XE in a Windows service application with a TIdCmdTCPServer serving clients using a TIdTCPClient.

With this function

```
function ConnectionCount: Integer;
begin
  if IdCmdTCPServer.Contexts = nil then
    Exit(0);
  with IdCmdTCPServer.Contexts do
  try
    Result := LockList.Count
  finally
    UnlockList
  end;
end;
```

I get a count of connections from clients to the server. Sometimes this count doesn't go down to zero even when all clients are closed. I guess those connections are dead somehow. On a site with 5 clients I've seen a connection count of 35 after some weeks of operation.

Is there a way to detect that a connection is dead and release it?

I suspect a connection can become dead if the client freezes or gets killed, but I don't know if that's the case here.

EDIT: here is the code from one of my TIdCmdTCPServer handlers:

```
procedure TDSA_Service.ModeHandler(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  R: TToolReply;
begin
  FBMutex.Enter;
  try
    try
      R := SystemServer.Mode(GetIntParam(0, 'SystemNo', ASender));
      try
        Reply(ASender, R)
      finally
        R.Free
      end
    except
      HandleException;
      Abort
    end
  finally
    FBMutex.Leave
  end
end;
```

HandleException is madExcept sending a bug report. Am I right that some indy exceptions shouldn't be caught here? Which exceptions?

Comment: That's not enough. You need to make use of `AContext.Data` to store the datetime of the connection, and then decide if the connection has been around for "too long" and if it has, "delete it".

Comment: @nolaspeaker that is a typical way of detecting when dead clients have become unresponsive before the OS reports errors for them, but that doesn't address the underlying issue of why dead clients are hanging around in the list for *weeks* at a time. That implies a logic bug is present in the OP's server code that is preventing dead client threads from being cleaned up properly (for instance, by swallowing exceptions that Indy needs to handle internally). But the OP didn't show their server code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I added a bit of server code to the question.

Comment: @JacobHavkrog that is not really helpful without seeing what `Reply()` and `HandleException()` actually do. And why are you wrapping everything inside a mutex? If multiple clients are connected, your server will only be able to handle 1 command total at a time, instead of handling multiple commands in parallel, like a typical server does.  Is that what you really want?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really determine if a connection is "dead". What I do is decide if the connection has been around for longer than say, 24 hours, and delete it if it has. 
I haven't cared about the issue that Remy raised "why connections hang around". My users also don't mind if they come in the next morning only to find that their client is no longer responsive. I hope this code answers more questions than it raises.

```
type
  TClientData = class(TObject)
    ClientName: string;
    ClientHost: string;
    ID: TDateTime;
  end;

type
  TDateTimeO = Class(TObject)
public
  Value: TDateTime;
  constructor Create(NewValue: TDateTime);
end;

const
  MAXCONNECT = (24 * 60 * 60);

procedure TfrmMain.IdCmdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  myClient: TClientData;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IdGlobal.IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;
  myClient := TClientData(AContext.Data);
  if myClient = nil then
  begin
     myClient := TClientData.Create;
     AContext.Data := myClient;
     myClient.ClientName := '<Unknown>';
     myClient.ClientHost := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
     myClient.ID := Now;
  end;
  // this actually happens elsewhere in my server code, but I've pasted
  // it here for convenience
  ListBox1.Items.AddObject(
    myClient.ClientName + '=' +
    FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', myClient.ID),
    TDateTimeO.Create(myClient.ID));

end;

procedure TfrmMain.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  ThisMoment: TDateTime;
  i, j: Integer;
  List: TList;
  Name: String;
  TimeStamp: TDateTime;
  MyClient: TClientData;
begin

  ThisMoment := Now;
  List := IdCmdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for i := ListBox1.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      // now terminate the actual connection (if it can be found)
      Name := Trim(TokenStr('=', ListBox1.Items[i], 1));
      TimeStamp := TDateTimeO(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]).Value;
      if (SecondsBetween(TimeStamp, ThisMoment) > MAXCONNECT)
      then
      begin
        for j := List.Count - 1 downto 0 do
        begin
          if Assigned(List[j]) then
          begin
            // is this the corresponding connection?
            myClient := TClientData(TIdContext(List[j]).Data);
            if (Name = myClient.ClientName) and
              (TDateTimeO(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]).Value = myClient.ID) then
            begin
              TIdContext(List[j]).Connection.Disconnect;
              BREAK;
            end;
          end;
        end; // next j
        // sometimes the connection isn't in the locklist for some reason
        // delete the listbox entry anyway
        TDateTimeO(ListBox1.Items.Objects[i]).Free;
        ListBox1.Items.Delete(i); // and delete the list entry
      end;
    end; // next i
  finally
    IdCmdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnLockList;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: This is one way to handle it. Just make sure you update each client's `TimeStamp` whenever the client sends data to the server. Just because a client is connected for a long time doesn't mean it isn't still communicating with the server. You should only kill clients that haven't sent any data for awhile.

Comment: Personally, I would not use the 2-loop approach like this. I would store the `TimeStamp` in `TClientData` (you even said as much in your earlier comment, but this code is not doing it), and then loop through only the `Contexts` list looking for stale clients to disconnect, letting the `OnConnect/OnDisconnect` events update the ListBox as needed (using the ListBox's `Objects` property to associate each `TIdContext` with each ListBox entry for easy lookup without having to compare client IDs).